# Does "DocuSign Connect API Service" has delivery notification confirmation log?

Tags: docusignapi

We are using "DocuSign Connect API Service", recently one of the request was not received at other end(consuming side).So we thoroughly debugged the issue and we are confirm that we did not received the request.

so only possibility is Docusign connect api service itself should not have sent the request I order to confirm that, I am looking for a log of all the API calls which where made to "consuming side" where do i get it ?

I check the "connect failure log" I could not find this request there and I have enabled the acknowledgement option as well in my account.

Answer (score 1):

If you're not seeing the message in the Connect Failures log (**Preferences >> Connect >> Failures**), then this means that either:

- The message was never sent in the first place (perhaps because "Allow Envelope Publish" in the Connect configuration wasn't enabled when the Envelope event occured, or because the Envelope event or Sender that occured did not match any of those selected in the Connect Configuration).

OR

- Connect sent a message that was not acknowledged by the listener app, but "Require Acknowledgement" was NOT selected in the Connect configuration when the Envelope event occured -- therefore no failure was logged within DocuSign.

OR

- The message was sent to your listener successfully ("Allow Envelope Publish" in the Connect configuration was enabled when the Envelope event occured, and the Envelope event or Sender matched those selected in the Connect Configuration).

As long as your Connect settings are configured with "Allow Envelope Publish" selected and "Require Acknowlegement" selected, the **Connect >> Failures** page should always list any messages that were sent but not successfully acknowledged by the listener.  Also, keep in mind that Connect will only send messages for the events and Senders that are selected in the Connect configuration.

Finally, if you select "Enable Log" in the Connect configuration, DocuSign will log (up to the most recent 100) messages sent, regardless of whether or not the message was successfully acknowledged.  This log (**Preferences >> Connect >> Logs**) can be helpful for troubleshooting as well, since examining contents of any individual message in the log will show you whether the message was successfully received/acknowledged.

Comment: @kimBradl I am experiencing similar issue again,is it possible to see the old logs which you have mentioned in the last paragraph (I know it will show only recent 100 logs) ?

Comment: @LohithMV This is the explanation I got from Docusign: `With the Docusign Connect in cases where multiple events for a single envelope or recipient are queued, only one set of XML data with the most recent change is published to a customer’s listener. When this happens it will not update till the next triggering event takes place. You can also run an envelope publish for the date range and it will update the status. Please let me know if this helps.`  So yeah, the Docusign Connect service isn't 100% reliable.